# Bloodhound, prefetching a json file saved in my files

Tags: javascript, json, bloodhound

I'm learning bloodhound through the examples given here: 
 https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#scrollable-dropdown-menu.

When I prefetch from the example JSON file of countries on Github it works fine.

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  prefetch: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/typeahead.js/gh-
  pages/data/countries.json'
});
```

However, when I save the JSON locally it stops working.

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    prefetch: 'file:///C:/Users/nicho/workspace/TypeAhead/Countries.json'    
});
```

When I put the link to the saved JSON in my browser it shows up identical to the JSON file on Github.

Why does Bloodhound have trouble reading my local JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a relative path like this:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    prefetch: 'Countries.json'    
});
```

Or as far as I understand your question it's using the already downloaded version of countries.json. You should clear the cache and clear your local storage (localStorage.clear()). Or you could add cache: false, like this:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    prefetch: {
        url: "countries.json",
        cache: false
    }
});
```